# istream's tellg/seekg cannot be protected from stack smashing (g++)?

Tags: c++, g++, istream, ssp

For a program that I'm writing, it is useful for me to calculate file sizes, which I calculate by using iostream's tellg and seekg functions, but this leads to a warning by -Wstack-protector. The following code reproduces the "problem":

```
#include <iostream>

std::streamsize get_file_size(std::ifstream& ifs) { // line 12 (in warning, below)
  const std::streamsize start = ifs.tellg();
  ifs.seekg(0,std::ios::end);
  const std::streamsize end = ifs.tellg();
  ifs.seekg(start);
  return (end-start);
}
```

g++ (flags: *-fstack-protector -Wstack-protector*, compiler version: *4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5)*, system: *Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64*) gives the warning:

*f.cc: In function ‘std::streamsize get_file_size(std::ifstream&)’:

f.cc:12: warning: not protecting function: no buffer at least 8 bytes long*

(I get the same results when I use GCC 4.5.2, downloaded and compiled from GNU directly.)

Is this expected from how stack smashing protection works (in general or by GCC) and/or how ifstream and seekg/tellg work? If so, can't this warning be ignored or is there something better that I can do?

**Edit**:

Actually, some of the code above is redundant. Just to clarify what's going on:

```
#include <iostream>

void f1(std::ifstream& ifs) { // line 6
    ifs.tellg();
}

void f2(std::ifstream& ifs) { // line 10
    // call seekg(std::streampos)
    ifs.seekg(0);
}

void f3(std::ifstream& ifs) {
    // call seekg(std::streamoff, std::ios_base::seekdir)
    ifs.seekg(0,std::ios::beg);
}
```

leads to g++ (same specs as above) warning:

*main.cc: In function ‘void f1(std::ifstream&)’:

main.cc:6: warning: not protecting function: no buffer at least 8 bytes long

main.cc: In function ‘void f2(std::ifstream&)’:

main.cc:10: warning: not protecting function: no buffer at least 8 bytes long*

Interestingly, `f3` does not trigger a warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wan't to see [**this.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629685/when-and-how-to-use-gccs-stack-protection-feature)

And the general advice is ***you really shouldn't care***, especially in your case, when you don't allocate any internal buffers that can be used to perform buffer overflow attack.

Comment: Thanks for the link (although I think it was reading that page that lead me to include -Wstack-protector in my program build!). The fact that I haven't put any buffers in `get_file_size` that can be exploited is the reason I asked the question: why is the warning even coming up? Even if I can ignore it in practise, I'd still prefer some knowledge about what's going on, for my benefit.

Comment: @Zorawar Well, I'm not that good at practical buffer overrun techniques, so I guess we'll have to wait for a person with a particular set of skills to explain how this can or can't be exploited )

Comment: maybe I should facilitate participation by mentioning that I found the code on a file called "NSA Project X humanoid language translator"? (Just kidding NSA! It was from MI6...)