# DIY stack protection

Tags: c++, g++, stack-overflow, android-ndk

I have a Android NDK project in C++. Customers are complaining of intermittent, irreproducible glitches. I suspect a memory corruption bug somewhere. I already have a malloc barrier; now I want to check for stack corruption.

GCC's -fstack-protector sounds too extreme to me; when it detects a bug, it just kills the program; I want something more user-friendly (a message, THEN kill :)). Question - is there a way to implement, under GCC, a stack consistency checker under programmer's control? I don't mind inline assembly.

Some predefined macros that expose the stack frame structure, for example, would come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

See the top-most answer to this question, on why `stack-protecter` is for hardening, and not debugging:  [When and how to use GCC's stack protection feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629685/when-and-how-to-use-gccs-stack-protection-feature)