# What is the gcc -fstack-protector -S XXX.c function?

Tags: gcc, c

I found out that for prevent to buffer overflow I can use that instruction (`gcc -fstack-protector -S XXX.c`).

For example, I have a file that name is `test.c` and that file has a buffer overflow, (ex. there is `char buf[10];` but I want to `strcpy(buf,"HelloUnixAndLinux")`)

In that case

```
$gcc -fstack-protector -S test.c
$cat test.s
```

will check the buffer and let me know as print out something long display including `stack_chk_fail`.

I want to know about those instructions but there is nothing explain about it.
(I just found out that way on Internet without any effect)

I want to know that

1. Those option always prevent buffer overflow automatically?
   (ex. if some function can lead to buffer overflow, automatically not process `strcpy` etc)
2. Is there  any way to check is my GCC provide a tool for checking stack smashing? Mine is GCC 4.4.6 Red Hat 4.4.6-4.
3. Is there any way to display warning about buffer overflow after `./a.out`?

Comment: The has been previously answered [**When and how to use GCC's stack protection feature?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629685/when-and-how-to-use-gccs-stack-protection-feature)

Comment: Even though the duplicate question is marked C++ rather than C, it applies to both the C and C++ compilers in the GCC (GNU Compiler Collection).  The options do not prevent buffer overflows; they add checking code to detect buffer overflows more quickly and reliably than not including the check.  You can try using the options with your compiler; if they don't work, you need to get a more modern compiler.  There'll be a runtime error if you have a buffer overflow.

Comment: I checked that explanation but still can't get the idea of that option. Do I have to type gcc -fstack-protector -S XXX.c everytime when I try to compile the program to get warning ?