# Program segfaulting in release version only

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

I have an executable that is segfaulting in release *but not in debug*. I assume it's a wrong call to a printf-family function.

When running i get this:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: ./mybin terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x777f5)[0x7f3a8914d7f5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f3a891ef21c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x117220)[0x7f3a891ed220]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x116789)[0x7f3a891ec789]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_default_xsputn+0x80)[0x7f3a891516c0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0xc90)[0x7f3a89123e10]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__vsprintf_chk+0x84)[0x7f3a891ec814]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__sprintf_chk+0x7d)[0x7f3a891ec76d]
./mybin[0x58b50e]
./mybin(main+0x2f3b)[0x41cfab]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f3a890f6840]
./mybin[0x421969]
======= Memory map: ========
...
7f3a8cd2e000-7f3a8cd34000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 Aborted (core dumped)
```

Running it in gdb yields these last lines:

```
#8  0x00007ffff3aa7814 in ___vsprintf_chk (s=0x7fffffffaee0 "Some Text - \377\377\177", flags=1, slen=20, format=0x894098 "Some Text - %d", 
    args=args@entry=0x7fffffffad68) at vsprintf_chk.c:82
#9  0x00007ffff3aa776d in ___sprintf_chk (s=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>, slen=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>) at sprintf_chk.c:31
#10 0x000000000058b50e in ?? ()
#11 0x000000000041cfab in main ()
```

The `"Some Text - %d"` comes from:

```
char aCharArr[20];
sprintf(aCharArr, "Some text - %d", anInt);
```

While it could do with a `memset` and `snprintf`, i've never had issues with these lines before. The int is always one digit.

I was unable to find that `0x58b50e` using `nm -CD`. How else can i more or less pinpoint this (besides going back the commit tree as i'm doing atm and [filling the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29630946/release-only-segfault-after-function-end-disapearing-with-vsnprintf) with `printf`s)?

Comment: Debug's builds tends to zero-initialize memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as it turns out, the original text (not `"Some text"`) took 19 chars plus the `%d`, which is "always" one digit. Even so, that's 20 chars in a `char aCharArr[20]`, producing a char array that is not `\0`-terminated.

Increasing the size of `aCharArr` (to the next multiple of 8 but that's just me) fixed it and using `snprintf` instead gave me peace of mind.

```
char aCharArr[24]; 
memset(aCharArr, '\0', sizeof(aCharArr));
sprintf(aCharArr, "Actual str orig len%d", anInt);
```

Compiling in debug with `-O2` as is used in release was also helpful, although the available information was enough.

Comment: Compiling with `-fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -g` would be considerably educational if you're using either gcc or clang.

Comment: [`snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might avoid that issue too.

Comment: @WhozCraig indeed, but activating sane flags in legacy code is insane. One at a time. ;)