# Why does my C http request cause an Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: c, sockets

I wanna make an HTTP request in C using sockets, so look at the following code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 //create the socket
 int network_socket;
 network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

 //specify an address for the socket
 struct sockaddr_in server_address;
 server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
 server_address.sin_port = htons(80);
 inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &server_address.sin_addr);


 //connect
 int connection_status = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
 if (connection_status == -1) {
  printf("There was an error making a connection to the remote socket\n\n");
 }

 //send information
 char message[14];
 strcpy(message , "GET http://matr.fr/v7 HTTP/1.1\r\n");
 send(network_socket, message, sizeof(message), 0);

 //receive information
 char server_response[2048];
 memset(server_response, '0',sizeof(server_response));
 int size = recv(network_socket, &server_response, sizeof(server_response), 0);

 //print the size
 printf("size is %d\n\n", size);

 //print the data
 printf("The server sent the response : %s\n", server_response);

 //close the socket
 close(network_socket);

 return 0;
}
```

When I run the program

> ./a.out "91.238.72.69"

I have an Illegal Instrution. But I wanna the HTML content of the page.

Comment: `"GET http://matr.fr/v7 HTTP/1.1\r\n"` looks like more than 13 chars to me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629685/when-and-how-to-use-gccs-stack-protection-feature

Comment: It's also not a complete HTTP request.

Comment: `memset(server_response, '0',sizeof(server_response));` What is the purpose of filling the whole buffer with `'0'` digits? You will probably not get a terminating `\0` byte from the server and when you print it, you will print beyond your buffer.